# Protractor is executing multiple times login by multicapability mode

Tags: protractor

I am newbie to protractor and javascript. I am trying to execute several tests in parallel using multiCapabilities. 
However when I do this,

```
await loginPage.login(testUserEmail, testUserPassword);
```

login function will be called by every chrome browsers.
I tried to avoid multiple login in parallel.
Is there any way for me to login at the beginning of the test and then run multiple chrome browsers for multiple spec.js?

Thank you in advance.
Shixiang

Answer (score 0):

When you login to a browser with your login credentials, your browser will save that in its cookies. Right now you are running the tests in parallel in multiple browsers and each browser has its own session maintenance. Because of this you will require to login through each browser so that the auth credential cookie is added to your browser.

This problem would only arise when executing tests in parallel. You would have to set the login credential in a cookie and add the same cookie to all your browsers in parallel. If your website uses a session token than that too needs to be added in your cookie when the browser starts up. This can be easily achieved by using browser.manage.addCookie() functionality. For further reading please refer to [this](https://chercher.tech/protractor/cookies-protractor#handling-cookies-with) website.